# Возвращение с TextBox.Text и PasswordBox.Password значения null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Посоветуйте, как организовать условие, или что изменить, что бы первая функция LOG возвращала значение 1 или 2 или 3, при пустом TextBox и PasswordBox

```
private int LOG(String log, String pass) {

            if (log == null && pass == null)  // Условие не выполняется
                return 1;

            if (log == null) // Условие не выполняется
                return 2;

            if (pass == null)   // Условие не выполняется
                return 3;

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\file.txt");

            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                String log_f = file.ReadLine();
                String pass_f = file.ReadLine();

                if (log == log_f && pass == pass_f)
                    return 4;

                if (log == log_f)
                    return 5;
            }

            return 6;
        }

private void LogIn(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String login = this.Log.Text;
            String password = this.Pass.Password;

                int parram = LOG(login, password);    /////Вызов функции LOG
                this.test.Text = parram.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: >>  return 1; ... return 6;

Обфускация для бедных? Погуглите enum.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно удобнее

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используй проверку `log == String.Empty`,
а лучше `String.IsNullOrEmpty(log)`

Типа

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(log) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(pass))  // Условие не выполняется
                return 1;
```